# Deselecting all elements from a multi-select dropdown in jQuery

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I have a multi-select drop down as following, where I have selected the options "Test 2" and "Test 3".

```
<select id="edit-rec" class="form-select" multiple="multiple" name="rec[]">
<option value="6012">Test 1</option>
<option value="8436">Test 2</option>
<option value="4689">Test 3</option>
<option value="6784">Test 4</option>
</select>
```

I have a button called "Deselect All". When this button is clicked, **all selected items should be deselected**. In this case, the items I previously selected, "Test 2" and "Test 3", should now become deselected.

How can I accomplish this using jQuery?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
$("#edit-rec option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

Comment: Better to use `$("#edit-rec option:selected").prop("selected", false);`

Answer (score 15):

Try -

```
$("#edit-rec > option").attr("selected",false);
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/LhSBu/

Comment: Your code looks very good. But could you explain the syntax $("#edit-rec > option")

Comment: `$("#edit-rec > option")` should select any `option` elements that are direct child elements the `#edit-rec` element. See - http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: I would suggest removing the `>` part. It doesn't make sense in this case, and would cause unexpected behavior using `<optgroup>` as a parent of `<option>`.

Comment: You need to use `prop` instead of `attr` these days, but yeah.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way that I found to unselect all options in a multi-select dropdown was using `.val([])`.

```
$("#select").val([]);
```

Comment: in my case $("select").val([]); worked perfectly,  thanks!

Answer (score 7):

On click of radio button you can use this

```
$("#edit-rec  option").each(function(){

    this.selected=false;

});
```

Answer (score 7):

It will remove all checked options from multiselect dropdownlist :

> $('#ddlTradeShow').multiselect("clearSelection");

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation to your answer, to make it more readable

Comment: didn't go through the documentation yet, but it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#edit-rec option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

Answer (score 3):

Can do something like this JS Fiddle for setting up the click on the radio button
http://jsfiddle.net/x5ck3/

```
$('#rdClear').click(

function() {
    $("#edit-rec option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#butt").click(function () {
    $("#edit-rec > option").removeProp("selected");
});
```

that's correct with new jQuery version

Comment: very bad idea, from https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/ This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is now another possibility directly provided by the API :

```
$('#edit-rec').multiSelect('deselect_all');
```

Works fine, here you can find more options about it : http://loudev.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vanilla [HTMLSelectElement DOM interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex), and also there's no need to iterate over all of the `<option>` elements. Either `selectedIndex` or `value` can be used:

```
$('#edit-rec')[0].selectedIndex = -1;
```

Or:

```
$('#edit-rec')[0].value = '';
```

Those will both work regardless of the `multiple` attribute. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bg13jrp/2/) for examples of various methods.

---

PS: For multiple elements you can use jQuery's `.each` (but be careful to return *non-false* from the callback), or the DOM collection's [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) (return values don't matter):

```
$('.all-the-selects').each((_,s) => s.selectedIndex = -1);
```

Or:

```
$('.all-the-selects').get().forEach(s => s.selectedIndex = -1);
```